# query_posts call sets is_home() to true

Tags: query-posts

I have a custom home page (`home.php`). I want to show the original home page's posts on `/blog/`.

I created a new blog.php file, with Template Name: Blog, added

```
query_posts('numberposts=5&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/index.php';
```

to the file.

The problem is that this `query_posts` call sets `is_home()` to true. I have some code in `header.php` that needs to be run only on the home page, but it runs on this template's pages too.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it this way. `query_posts()` should not be used most of the time and you are really hacking things up here with direct template inclusion and such.

1. Create new page *Blog* (no template).
2. Go to `Settings` > `Reading`.
3. Assign this page as `Posts page`.

Comment: For some reason, this is making my Blog page show home.php. These are the settings I'm using: http://cl.ly/1t2W1j1z3p2i2q011G2R

Comment: @Dogbert `home.php` is template supposed to be used for list of posts that's why it picks it up. Use `front-page.php` for front page or do same thing with creating dedicated page for it and assign template to it. See [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in Codex.